# Is there a way to modify a line in this vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

A Guy named black cat helped me writing this code (i thank him a lot).
The code is:

```
Public Function CDZEman(Compte As String, Cle As Range, Optional mois As String, Optional annee As String) As String


    C1 = Right("00000000000000000000" & Compte, 20)
    Set CleRange = Cle
    cler = WorksheetFunction.Sum(CleRange)
    cler = CStr(Format(cler * 100, "0000000000000"))
    C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.Rows.Count, "0000000"))
    If mois = "" Then mois = Month(Now())
    If annee = "" Then annee = Year(Now())

    mois = Right(CStr(Format(mois, "00")), 2) & Right(CStr(Format(annee, "0000")), 4)
    C3 = Space(14) & "0"

    CDZEman = "*" & C1 & cler & C2 & mois & C3


End Function
```

I have an issue with this ligne:

```
C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.Rows.Count, "0000000"))
```

When I choose for example the range G:G, the whole column G, i want to get the Number of only rows that contain amounts, and ignoring the blank cells and the first cell which contain the name of the column.
Thanks a lot in advance ( and a special thank goes to black car).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleaset try:

```
    ' Column selection
    If Cle.Rows.Count = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
        ' CountA get the quantity of non-blank cells
        rowCnt = Application.CountA(Cle) - 1
    Else
        ' current logic
        rowCnt = Cle.Rows.Count
    End If
    C2 = CStr(Format(rowCnt, "0000000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about all of your possible scenarios

but you may take advantage of `SpecialCells` method of `Range` object

```
C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1, "0000000"))
```